# Remove trailing zeros from ggplot axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I display the x-axis tick labels without trailing zeros? In other words, just as they're listed in the breaks argument.

```
d = data.frame(y = runif(10000, 0.0001, 1))

options(scipen = 999)
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(x = y)) + geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color='black', size=8))
```

[image]

Comment: Use the `labels` argument of `scale_x_log10`? Something like `labels=c(1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001)`.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal, that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just turn the number into character and then plot it!

```r
d = data.frame(y = runif(10000, 0.0001, 1))

options(scipen = 999)
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(x = y)) + 
geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001),
                labels = function(x) as.character(x)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color='black', size=8)) 
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>